# Handling GET requests - Apache HttpClient vs java.net.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

Does the Apache HttpClient handle GET requests differently compared to java.net.HttpURLConnection?

I tried making a GET request to a URL which returns a redirect using both methods. While the response code from HttpURLConnection returns a 302 as expected, making the same call using HttpClient results in a 200.

Below is my code:

```
// Using Apache HttpClient
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(authUrl);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  //Returns 200

// Using java.net.HttpURLConnection
URL obj = new URL(authUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();  //Returns 302
```

This is my first time using Apache HttpClient, so my code might be wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the headers for "Location" - you can get the redirect from that. `for (Header header : response.getHeaders("Location")) { redirectLink = header.getValue(); }`

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't have any "Location" header because the response is 200, and not a 302.

Answer (score 1):

[Handling GET requests - Apache HttpClient vs java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979301/handling-get-requests-apache-httpclient-vs-java-net-httpurlconnection)
If you need to walk through a chain of redirects, you should set redirects disabled for HttpPost/HttpGet (HttpRequestBase), for example:

```
public void disableRedirect(HttpRequestBase request) {
    request.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setRedirectsEnabled(false).build());
}
```

After that you will get expected 302 response code with `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and may read headers as @Ascalonian said

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off automatic redirect handling. Most likely HttpClient redirects to a location specified in 302 response, while HUC for some reason does not